# FireDAC ExecSQL with Params, C++ (or escape GUID braces)

Tags: ms-access, c++builder, guid, firedac

I'm using C++Builder (XE7) and FireDAC, trying to insert a row into a table with a column of GUID datatype into a Microsoft Access database with FDConnection.ExecSQL.

SQL which works in any tool which allows me to execute SQL directly to the Database:

```sql
INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) 
VALUES ('xyz', {guid {7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}})
```

(the above GUID syntax is apparently what Microsoft wants for this odd Database column type)

So, trying to execute this SQL in my program...

My first attempt:

```
FDConnection1->ExecSQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('xyz', {guid {7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}})");
```

Fails because apparently curly braces '{', '}' are used in FireDAC preprocessing (which I never knew about, but looks pretty useful).  FireDAC docs here say to escape special characters like '{' by doubling them up.

Docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_%28FireDAC%29#Special_Character_Processing

So, my next attempt:

```
FDConnection1->ExecSQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('xyz', {{guid {{7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}}}})");
```

Still doesn't work.  Fails with a preprocessor error for macro.

Finally, it looks like the ExecSQL method is overloaded with a signature that allows passing params, so I tried this:

```
FDConnection1->ExecSQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('xyz', :guid)", ["{guid {7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}}"]);
```

But this simple [ param, param, ... ] syntax given in the examples is Delphi, not C++.  There is no C++ example.

Doing some research, I found that there is a macro which might help with these types of method signatures in C++.  Its syntax is:
ARRAYOFCONST(( param, param, ... ))

So, my next attempt is:

```
FDConnection1->ExecSQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('xyz', :guid)", ARRAYOFCONST(( "{guid {7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}}" )));
```

Which fails with:

> [bcc32 Error] ReportHeaderFrm.cpp(487): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TFDCustomConnection::ExecSQL(UnicodeString,OpenArray,unsigned int)'

I'm out of ideas.  Any help?

Comment: Try setting `ResourceOptions.EscapeExpand` to False to stop FireDAC from processing the `{`

Comment: Hm, this is the place where `Params[].AsGUID` would probably fail.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the string directly: `UnicodeString sql = Format("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('%s', {guid %s}", ARRAYOFCONST(("xyz", "{7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}")));` and then just call `FDConnection1->ExecSQL(sql);`?

Comment: @crefird - The ability to turn off macro processing for this one command might get me past this problem, but I was looking for the correct way to escape '{' and '}' or to use the ExecSQL signature with the Params parameter from C++.  Thank you for the answer that would get me past my problem, but it seems a workaround rather than the proper solution.

Comment: @RodrigoGómez - How would your suggestion be any different from my first attempt? Your sql variable, after the Format, would contain the same UnicodeString constant as what I pass in my first attempt, no?

Comment: @Scribe You're right, sorry. I got lost in the different attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call that kind of functions, you need the macro OPENARRAY, not ARRAYOFCONST. So, changing your last attempt for this should pass the compiler error:

```
FDConnection1->ExecSQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (:param1, :param2)", OPENARRAY(Variant, ("xyz", "{guid {7F60EFE4-106D-4678-A838-8BEB541F2A74}}")));
```